# App crashes due Memory Warning with heavy images

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a quite big `NSArray` with almost 100 images, I'm displaying these images in a table view. My problem is that after I scrolled through the array, my project crashes due Memory Warning. I'm getting no errors or other issues just Xcode logs `Received Memory Warning` message 4-5 times and then the app crashes.

I've tried to use `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method to solve the problem, but this solution doesn't helped.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

   arrayOfImages = nil;
}
```

I also tried it in the `viewDidUnload` method at least to clear the memory when the user goes to another view, but it didn't worked too.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    arrayOfImages = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];

}
```

How could I solve this problem? I need to use that images, but it's really annoying that it crashes after the user checked 40-50 images.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"imgCell";

    BTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to display the images?

Comment: @JScarry Sure, I've updated it.

Comment: From what I understand from your code, 'arrayOfImages' hold the images names, and not the images themselves, So I doubt that setting an array of strings to nil will clear enough memory when receiving a memory warning...

Comment: @AMI289 you are right, it holds just the image names. Do you have any idea how could I solve it?

Comment: It still isn't really clear to me why this is happening.....Have you set the 'imgCell' table view cell class to BTableVieCell in storyboard?

Comment: What is the approximate file size of each image? are you using thumbnails to present in your cell or are you scaling down a 10MB image for each cell?

Comment: @AMI289 an average image is 3-4mb, the smallest is 1,5 the biggest is about 5-6mb.

Comment: I would suggest to create a thumbnails of those images, and use those thumbnails in the table view cells. I'm guessing that this is what causing the high memory usage, since you app generate several cells at a time, maybe using images of that size is too much for it... Plus, as JScarry mentioned below, if imageNamed is caching those images, you are caching few hundreds of MB just with those cells.

Comment: Plus, I don't think it's performance-efficient to always create cells with images of those size.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for imageNamed:,

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists… If you have an
>   image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it
>   does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create
>   your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will keep your
>   single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving
>   the memory use characteristics of your app.

Comment: But these aren't single-use images. The user will scroll up and down a table and see them multiple times. `imageNamed:` should be used here.

Comment: But if the app crashes, then most likely it is a memory issue. imageNamed is intended to be used for things like navigation buttons, recording and playback icons, etc. Things that stay on the screen for the duration of the app. His images are transient so they should be removed when not needed. I had almost the exact same issue and making this change made it go away.